# Include a table into html website by date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a table from an external HTML file displayed into my website. I'm using this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tableinclude").load("table.html"); 
});
```

`tableinclude` is the id of the `<div>` where the table is shown and `table.html` is the HTML file containing the table. Now, I need to change the script so that it shows a different table everyday, according to the date.

For example:

- first of july : table1.html
- second of july: table2.html

Could somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: I have trief to use a jquery from this source: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/

Comment: but can't manage to combine both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current date from the `Date` object in JavaScript.  Something like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentDay = currentDate.getUTCDate();
```

Then you can use that value when fetching the HTML file.  Something like this:

```
$('#tableinclude').load('table' + currentDay + '.html');
```

This should fetch the `tableX.html` file for any given day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe like this, If I understood your question correctly.

```
$(function(){
    $("#tableinclude").load("table"+new Date().getUTCDate()+".html"); 
});
```